# Flutter - Integrate an API in UI using Getx

Tags: flutter, api, dart, flutter-getx

I am trying to integrate API with UI in Flutter using GetX. But while retrieving the product from the JSON file I got the below errors.

**Error**:

> The parameter 'id, title, description, price, discount, rating, stock,
> brand, category, thumbnail, images' can't have a value of 'null'
> because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'.

So I used the 'null safety' method. then I get the below error when I call that class.

`var productList = ProductModel().obs;`

**Error**: The named parameter 'id, name, description....' is required, but there's no corresponding argument.

Json code:

```
ProductModel productModelFromJson(String str) =>
    ProductModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String productModelToJson(ProductModel data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class ProductModel {
  ProductModel({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.description,
    required this.price,
    required this.discountPercentage,
    required this.rating,
    required this.stock,
    required this.brand,
    required this.category,
    required this.thumbnail,
    required this.images,
  });

  int id;
  String title;
  String description;
  int price;
  double discountPercentage;
  double rating;
  int stock;
  String brand;
  String category;
  String thumbnail;
  List<String> images;

  factory ProductModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ProductModel(
        id: json["id"],
        title: json["title"],
        description: json["description"],
        price: json["price"],
        discountPercentage: json["discountPercentage"]?.toDouble(),
        rating: json["rating"]?.toDouble(),
        stock: json["stock"],
        brand: json["brand"],
        category: json["category"],
        thumbnail: json["thumbnail"],
        images: List<String>.from(json["images"].map((x) => x)),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "title": title,
        "description": description,
        "price": price,
        "discountPercentage": discountPercentage,
        "rating": rating,
        "stock": stock,
        "brand": brand,
        "category": category,
        "thumbnail": thumbnail,
        "images": List<dynamic>.from(images.map((x) => x)),
      };
}
```

Error code:

```
import 'package:get/state_manager.dart';
import 'package:practice/apimodule/api_service.dart';
import 'package:practice/productmodule/models/product_model.dart';
import 'package:get/get_rx/get_rx.dart';

class ProductController extends GetxController {
  var isLoading = true.obs;
  var productList = ProductModel().obs;
}
```

Comment: remove `required` from all variable and put `?` after every variable declarations.

Comment: To create model use this https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/ . And that model you should use in your app.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the model class which has null value either you may change your data type to var or use the null check operator. I had update your model class, just replace & check it.

```
ProductModel productModelFromJson(String str) =>
ProductModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String productModelToJson(ProductModel data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class ProductModel {
 ProductModel({
 this.id,
 this.title,
 this.description,
 this.price,
 this.discountPercentage,
 this.rating,
 this.stock,
 this.brand,
 this.category,
 this.thumbnail,
 this.images,
});

int? id;
String? title;
String? description;
int? price;
double? discountPercentage;
double? rating;
int? stock;
String? brand;
String? category;
String? thumbnail;
List<String> images;

factory ProductModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ProductModel(
    id: json["id"],
    title: json["title"],
    description: json["description"],
    price: json["price"],
    discountPercentage: json["discountPercentage"]?.toDouble(),
    rating: json["rating"]?.toDouble(),
    stock: json["stock"],
    brand: json["brand"],
    category: json["category"],
    thumbnail: json["thumbnail"],
    images: List<String>.from(json["images"].map((x) => x)),
  );

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "title": title,
    "description": description,
    "price": price,
    "discountPercentage": discountPercentage,
    "rating": rating,
    "stock": stock,
    "brand": brand,
    "category": category,
    "thumbnail": thumbnail,
    "images": List<dynamic>.from(images.map((x) => x)),
    };
}
```

just replace the mode class & let me know if any issue.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But now I get an error in the last line.   Error: The method 'map' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.
"images": List<dynamic>.from(images.map((x) => x)),

Comment: Use this in last line - List<String>? images;

Comment: Yes, I gave that operator to all declarations. An error occurs in the last line of that class. Line: "images": List<dynamic>.from(images.map((x) => x)),                                       Error: The method 'map' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.